# Parent CSS properties arent being overwritten

Tags: html, css

I have a parent CSS property which seems cant be overwritten by !important. what other options to I have? I'm trying to get rid of the margin-left: 30 property.

Div  code

```
.difference-ul  {
margin-left: 0 !important;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

The parent CSS property below which is applying to the above div class

```
    .Rte ul, .Rte ol {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your code like this:

```
   .Rte ul, .Rte ol .difference-ul  {
margin-left: 0 !important;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your actual devtools elements?

Comment: hmmmm, something I noticed the .difference-ul was missing in the dev section. I placed the css code higher up.... and now its working... does css implement code based on how further up their code is?